# Quickest way to render a Uint8Array to a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am receiving a `Uint8Array` with RGBA values, as well as some information which part of the image has been updated. What is the quickest way to render this raw bitmap information back to a canvas? I have been using a 2D rendering context to manually loop though the array and set pixel information, but this is incredibly slow:

```
let imageData = new ImageData(1920, 1080);
for (var i=0;i < args.frameBuffer.length; i+=4) {
    imageData.data[i]   = args.frameBuffer[i];
    imageData.data[i+1] = args.frameBuffer[i+1];
    imageData.data[i+2] = args.frameBuffer[i+2];
    imageData.data[i+3] = args.frameBuffer[i+3];
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, args.dirtyX, args.dirtyY, args.dirtyWidth, args.dirtyHeight);
```

What would be a more efficient way to do this? Would WebGL be more performant than a 2D context? Native or via something like Three.js?

Comment: Take a look at [textures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL). Particularly, at [texImage2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) method.

Comment: To move data between typed arrays you can use `imageDataTo.data.set(imageDataFrom.data)` To copy part of the data (a rect) use `set` and `subArray` to move rows. For each row (imageData is id) `idTo.data.set(idFrom.data.subArray((yFrom*idFrom.width+xFrom)*4,width),(yTo*idTo.width+xTo)*4)` If you need to check each pixel you can create a Uint32Array to handle a pixel in one read/write with `data32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer)` Note little/big endian come into play. Also canvas is an image so you can render `context.drawImage(canvasFrom,...` from canvas to canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gl.TexSubImage2D to update a texture and then blit your texture as whole. But TexSubImage2D has performance problem because it has to wait previous rendering to complete before updating texture for next frame.

Better method could be using preserveDrawingBuffer bit for webgl and then use two textures in round robin fashion with TexImage2D. To render only dirty area you need to setup vertex data for DrawArrays based on dirty coordinates.

WebGL would still have to copy data around a lot but maybe those copy paths are better optimized than putImageData. But there is serious danger that webgl can be slower because drivers often optimize for use case where texture images are static and used for multiple renderings. That makes it faster to render but slower to upload texture data.

To solve the costly texture upload problem OpenGL has multiple extensions supporting fast image upload but a bit slower rendering. Too bad those extensions aren't practical for webgl.

But your copy loop looks a lot like you are receiving whole frame buffer every time even tough it is only partially updated.

If you could do something like

```
let imageData = new ImageData(args.frameBuffer, args.dirtyWidth, args.dirtyHeight);
context.putImageData(imageData, args.dirtyX, args.dirtyY);
```

Of course your current interface could be repeated with

```
let imageData = new ImageData(args.frameBuffer, 1920, Math.floor((args.frameBuffer.length + 4*1919)/(4*1920)));
context.putImageData(imageData, 0,0, args.dirtyX, args.dirtyY, args.dirtyWidth, args.dirtyHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I was using the entire frameBuffer. That already  speeds up things considerably.